# Помогите дополнить функцию

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Есть xml:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <isbn>456-789</isbn>
    </item>
    <item>
        <isbn></isbn>
    </item>
</items>
```

Есть общая формула:

```
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B09
#200: ^AАнализ износа бандажей колесных пар грузовых электровозов 2эс10 и вл11
#700: ^310000814^AБуйносов^BА. П.
#701: ^AДенисов^BД. С.
#463: ^CЗакономерности и тенденции развития науки в современном обществе^J2015^GАэтерна^DУфа^S9-14
#963: ^EСборник статей международной научно-практической конференции, Уфа, 05.12.2015^I978-5-906836-54-0
#1105: Статья в сборнике трудов конференции
*****
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B09
#200: ^AАнализ причин отказов подшипников электровозов и пути их снижения
#700: ^310000814^AБуйносов^BА. П.
#701: ^310005915^AМишин^BЯ. А.
#463: ^CИнновационный транспорт - 2016: специализация железных дорог^J2017^GУральский государственный университет путей сообщения^DЕкатеринбург^S220-225
#963: ^EМатериалы международной научно-технической конференции, Екатеринбург, 17.11.2016^INone
#1105: Статья в сборнике трудов конференции
*****
```

В поле 963 в самом конце прописывается isbn, но иногда их в item не бывает и возникает None.
И есть функция:

```
def get_isbn(item) -> str:
    isbn = item.find("isbn")
    return isbn
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for item in root.select('item'):
    isbn = get_isbn(item)
```

На данном этапе, эта функция возвращает цифры если они есть, а если их нет возвращает None. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как дополнить функцию, чтобы, если `isbn` есть в `item`, вернуть `isbn`. А если `isbn` нет в `item`, просто идти дальше по коду без None.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82129/discussion-on-question-by-ireen1985---).

Answer (score 0):

Решила проблему так:

```
def get_isbn(item) -> str:
    isbn = item.find("isbn")
    if isbn:
        return '^I' + str(isbn)
    else:
        return ''
```

Comment: Что вы к этому `if isbn in item:` прицепились? :) Оно, похоже, работает, но зачем? :) Просто используйте `if isbn:`, если в `isbn` будет `None`, оно проверку не пройдет. Если хотите именно на None проверить, тогда: `if isbn is not None:`

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю за правки, убрала лишнее и все сработало!!! Спасибо большое!!!